# C# LINQ INNER JOIN is returning wrong count

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I have the following sql with JOIN but which returns a record count for 50 but when I convert it to LINQ, I am not getting the matching count. I noticed that when I add the ON clause, the visual studio intellisense dropdown does not show the ID property for the 2nd table. I am wondering if that is an issue.

Here is the simple SQL

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 T1 JOIN Table2 T2 ON T1.MyId = T2.MyId WHERE T1.IsCompleted
```

Here is my lamba LINQ with the comment where the VC Intellisense is not working right. For table2, the intellisense dropdown, it is only showing Equals, GetHashCode, GetType, and ToString. Just manually type the MyId and everything successfully builds but the count is too high. Thanks

```
var test = this.myDbContent.Table1
           .Join (this.myDbContent.Table2
             table1 => table1.MyId,
             table2 => table2.MyId, 
             (table1, table2) => new { table1, table2}
           )
           .Where (joinedTable => joinedTable.Table1.IsCompleted == 1)
```

Comment: There's a strong likelihood your application doesn't want a `JOIN`. Have you considered using related entities, e.g. `var testx = this.myDbContent.Table1.Select(t => new Tuple<int,int>(t.MyId, t.Table2.MyId));`

Comment: I realize that's not a direct answer to your question, but LINQ with Entity Framework is not always great as a direct statement-by-statement replacement for SQL. If you use the Entity model you may get better and easier results.

Comment: ORMs prove to be a headake and a source of wasted time for things that can be achieved easily and efficiency through SQL.

Comment: @Tarik, so just try `linq2db`

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv Had a quick look at it. All is well as long as things a simple (as for other ORMs). Where do joins happen with such simple library? AFAIK the entity framework is able to deal with that and build a SQL statement that include joins. Dealing with complex queries is yet another story. My conclusion is that ADO.Net with DataTables offer a much better framework.

Comment: @Tarik, ok. We use `linq2db` for 6 years and think it is the best framework for the SQL database and especially complex queries ;)

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv, Well, I should have a closer look before passing judgement. I will give it a shot. Sheers.

Comment: @Tarik, you can start from extension for EF Core, which extends LINQ https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore and gives bulk operations for free.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Join is the simple LINQ operation, but better understandable via LINQ Query.

```cs
var query = 
    from t1 in myDbContent.Table1
    join t2 in myDbContent.table2 on t1.MyId equals t2.MyId
    where t1.IsCompleted
    select new 
    {
        t1,
        t2
    };
```

If you still have different results, probably `MyId` is nullable field and EF also matches  nulls.

It can be disabled via options configuration:

```cs
builder.UseSqlServer(ceConnection, x => x.UseRelationalNulls(true));
```